# Where should AsyncTask be?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android programming. I would like to get some advices about AsyncTask. I have created a main activity and one fragment in which i will display content. The use for AsyncTask in my program is to download data from internet. So, the question would be: where it should be? In the fragment's class or activity's?

Comment: You can have your async class in fragment or activity, depends on where are your parameters and where do you want to show data from onPostExecute.

Comment: Either way will work.

Comment: make sure your asynctask do something quick because any rotation will destroy it.. instead of asynctask I would suggest you do background task in service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three choices:

1. You can make it an inner class inside of the Fragment. This is probably OK if this asynchronous task is only specific to the fragment and you won't ever reuse it
2. You can make it an inner class inside of the Activity. The is better if you have one activity that controls many Fragments that may reuse the same asynchronous task.
3. You can make it a class of its own if you plan to reuse it in man places in your application or even    if you just want it neater. If you do plan on reusing it but the places that are reusing it may need some slight differences, then you might want to abstract it to make it flexible.

Hope that helps.